# Qual a melhor opção para substituir um Switch com muitos cases no C#?

Tags: c#, switch

Sou iniciante na programação e gostaria de uma ideia.

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que recebe pacotes UDP de vários clients.

Esses pacotes são referentes a toda ação que o usuário executa nesse client, seja solicitar um relatório, arrastar um arquivo, deletar um cadastro etc.

Nesses pacotes vem diversas informações (de acordo com a ação executada). A única coisa em comum em cada pacote desse é a primeira informação, que é um inteiro, referente ao "ID" do pacote.

Existem pouco mais de 120 pacotes diferentes ao todo.

Meu código está da seguinte forma, porém eu queria quebrar melhor esse switch, pois ficou extenso demais.

Entidade do pacote:

```
public class DadosDoPacote
{
    public byte[] Dados { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }

    public DadosDoPacote()
    {
       Data = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Exemplo do "processo" em si:

```
var pacote = ObterPacote(); //retorna um DadosDopacote();
var id = pacote.Dados.LerInt();

switch (id)
{
   case 1: //Login
   {
         var login = pacote.Dados.LerString();
         var senha = pacote.Dados.LerString();

         _repositorio.Login(login, senha, pacote.Data);
   }
   break;

   case 2: //Autenticação do terminal
   {
         var terminalId = pacote.Dados.LerInt();
         var section = pacote.Dados.LerInt();

         _repositorio.Autenticacao(terminalId, section, pacote.Data);
   }
   break;

   ...

   case 118: //Gerar relatório
   {
         var usuarioId = pacote.Dados.LerString();
         var tipoRelatorio = pacote.Dados.LerInt();
         var dataInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(pacote.Dados.LerString());
         var dataFim = Convert.ToDateTime(pacote.Dados.LerString());

         _repositorio.Relatorio(usuarioId, tipoRelatorio, dataInicio, dataFim);
   }
   break;

   default:
         Console.WriteLine($"Pacote desconhecido. Id: {id}. Tamanho: {pacote.Dados.Length}");
   break;
}
```

Consigo quebrar ele em mais classes por exemplo? Como?

Obs.: Não é possível alterar a forma como o client manda os pacotes pois é uma aplicação de um terceiro no projeto.

Obrigado!

Comment: Consegue dar mais contexto ou colocar mais código? O que alguns cases fazem? É bem raro switch de 128 cenários, então possivelmente tem uma forma mais simples de fazer o que você quer, mas precisamos de mais código/info/contexto

Comment: Ok, vou incrementar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar um dicionário para colocar cada "processo" e separar ele por responsabilidades como classes no exemplo, adicionar todos e chamar apenas a execução.

```
public class PacoteDados
{
    private DadosDoPacote ObterPacote()
    {
        return default;
    }

    private IProcessoPacote EncontraProcesso(int id)
    {
        if (_processoPacotes.TryGetValue(id, out IProcessoPacote processo))
        {
            return processo;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private readonly Dictionary<int, IProcessoPacote> _processoPacotes;

    public PacoteDados()
    {
        _processoPacotes = new Dictionary<int, IProcessoPacote>()
        {
            { 1,   new Login() },
            { 2,   new AutenticacaoTerminal() },
            //...
            { 118, new GerarRelatorio() },
        };
    }


    public void ExemploExecucao()
    {
        var pacote = ObterPacote(); //retorna um DadosDopacote();
        int id = 0; //var id = pacote.Dados.LerInt();

        var processo = EncontraProcesso(id);

        if(processo == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Pacote desconhecido. Id: {id}. Tamanho: {pacote.Dados.Length}");
            return;
        }

        processo.Executar(pacote);
    }
}

public interface IProcessoPacote
{
    void Executar(DadosDoPacote pacote);
}


public class Login : IProcessoPacote
{
    public void Executar(DadosDoPacote pacote)
    {
        //var login = pacote.Dados.LerString();
        //var senha = pacote.Dados.LerString();

        //_repositorio.Login(login, senha, pacote.Data);
    }
}

public class AutenticacaoTerminal : IProcessoPacote
{
    public void Executar(DadosDoPacote pacote)
    {
        //var terminalId = pacote.Dados.LerInt();
        //var section = pacote.Dados.LerInt();

        //_repositorio.Autenticacao(terminalId, section, pacote.Data);
    }
}

public class GerarRelatorio : IProcessoPacote
{
    public void Executar(DadosDoPacote pacote)
    {
        //var usuarioId = pacote.Dados.LerString();
        //var tipoRelatorio = pacote.Dados.LerInt();
        //var dataInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(pacote.Dados.LerString());
        //var dataFim = Convert.ToDateTime(pacote.Dados.LerString());

        //_repositorio.Relatorio(usuarioId, tipoRelatorio, dataInicio, dataFim);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

man vc pode usar o proprio if e else :
if(code (/* a condição desse if( maior ">", menor"<" diferente "!="*/){
algo que torne o problema verdadeiro
}
else{
caso contrario é falso
}
OBS: varia muito do que está pedindo no enunciado, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: O problema verdadeiro é o tamanho da classe, quero deixa-la menor. Antes do switch eu já utilizava ifs mas fica extenso demais.

Comment: Creio eu que nao tem como fugir disso, pois também não sou muito experiente nesse ramo de programação kkk tbm comecei tem pouco tempo